# cannot upload audio files in Bale bot using python-bale-bot

Tags: python, bale-messenger

I intend to create a bot in a Telegram-like messenger called Bale that should send audio files. I am using [python-bale-bot](https://github.com/python-bale-bot) which is a wrapper for Bale Messenger API. When I try to open the mp3 file and read it and pass it to the method, I get an error that I did not find its solution anywhere.

Here is the code:

```
"""keyboard handler"""
@client.listen(EventType.CALLBACK)
async def when_receive_callback(callback: CallbackQuery):
    if callback.data == "audio":
        audio_file = open("/path_to/audio_file.mp3","rb")
        audio = audio_file.read()
        await callback.message.reply_document(audio)
```

And when the users clicks on the keyboard button and the callback is sent, I get the following error:

```
error on_callback Can not serialize value type: <class 'int'>
 headers: {}
 value: 800646076
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I found the solution to this issue. To see the complete discussion, read what the library maintainer suggested [here](https://github.com/python-bale-bot/python-bale-bot/discussions/13).

And if you don't feel like reading it, here's the summary:
To send an audio file in Bale chatbot, we can follow these steps:

1. First, send the audio file to the bot in Bale messenger in order to find its `file_id`.

```
@bot.listen(bale.EventType.MESSAGE)
async def on_callback(message: bale.Message):
    if message.document:
        print(message.document.file_id)
```

2. Now that we have the file_id, we can send the file to them, as if the bot is forwarding a document message.

```
@bot.listen(bale.EventType.CALLBACK)
async def on_callback(callback: bale.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.chat.send_document(document = "Your file id", ...)
```